# How can I curl the names of all the nodes in a jenkins instance using the Jenkins API?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, nodes, jenkins-api

In the scripts console, i can get information on the nodes with a groovy script like:

```
for (nodes in Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
if (nodes.labelString=="") {
println(nodes.getNodeName()) } }
```

or

```
for (nodes in Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
   println(nodes.getNodeName()) 
}
```

Which returns a list of node names for the entire Jenkins instance.

I want to do the same thing with something like:

```
curl -X get http://<jenkins-endpoint>/nodes/api/json -d json
```

Does the Jenkins API allow for that or can I only interact with jobs as shown in the link below? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

Answer (score 2):

JenkinsAPI works with almost anything in Jenkins. You can try the following to get a list of all nodes in my case physical computers listed in jenkins instance.

XML

```
http://jenkinsinstance/computer/api/xml
```

JSON

```
http://jenkinsinstance/computer/api/json
```

This will give you following:

[image: Data snapshot from jenkins instance]

1 - class type of the node

2 - Labels you have assigned

3 - The display name of the node.

This is the list of all nodes in jenkins instance.

Comment: Hats off! I didn't know that this API exists. Too bad that it isn't mentioned on the main API page `http://jenkins/api`. Do you know of a reference page containing a list of all available APIs?

Comment: No i am not aware of any reference page containing all available API :(

Comment: Ah...there's the sentence at the beginning of every `/api` page: "_Many objects of Jenkins provide the remote access API. They are available at `/.../api/` where "`...`" portion is the object for which you'd like to access._". So, it's always `.../<page_path>` + `/api.` Well...RTFM to myself.